# Как получить коллекцию данных, в которой есть подколлекция в firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-database, firestore

Есть такая структура в firebase:
[image: коллекция users]

Мне нужно вернуть коллекцию пользователей с адрессом при подписке на getUsers

Вот неполноценный код:

```
class User{
    
      String name;
      String surname;
      Address address;
    
    
      User({this.name, this.surname});
    
      Stream<List<User>> getUsers(CollectionReference firestoreInstance) {
        firestoreInstance.collection("users").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
            firestoreInstance
                .collection("users")
                .document(result.documentID)
                .collection("address")
                .getDocuments()
                .then((querySnapshot) {
              querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
                print(result.data);
              });
            });
          });
        });
    
        //Мне нужно вернуть коллекцию пользователей с адрессом при подписке getUsers.listen((users) => ...)
    
      }
    }
    
    class Address{
      String city;
      String region;
    
      Address(this.city, this.region);
    }
```

Как вернуть stream c заполненными данными user?

Answer (score 1):

`Snapshots` вернет вам `stream`, а дальше выборку делать через `where` и тд.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots();
```

В данном примере получите поток, всех пользователей.